# An unusual equivalent form of Riemann hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

Let $G(x)=\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$, where $\mu$ is the Mobius function. From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873632/riemann-hypothesis-and-sum-limits-k-leq-n-left-frac-mukk-right2) and its answer, its mention the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to $G(x)=O(x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$.

I have never heard of this, the closet thing I have heard is the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to $M(x)=O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$, where $M(x)=\sum_{k\leq x}\mu(k)$, the Mertens function. I have tried to prove the above fact but did not succeed. So I would like to ask for reference for the above equivalent form of the Riemann hypothesis(the $G(x)$ one), better to contain a proof of it.

Comment: [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) gives $$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}}  = \frac{{M(x)}}{x} + \int_1^x {\frac{{M(t)}}{{t^2 }}{\rm d}t} .
$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: Can you write an answer? I try to bounded the integral term, but then the integral seems unbounded when $\epsilon>0$, also there are constant term that didn't cancel out.

Comment: Some explicit bounds can be found at the link below. One such bound is $$|M(t)|<\frac{t}{\log(t)^{11/9}}$$ for $x>1000$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function#Known_upper_bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) gives
$$
G(x):=\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}}  = \frac{{M(x)}}{x} + \int_1^x {\frac{{M(t)}}{{t^2 }}{\rm d}t} .
$$
Assume RH. Then $M(x)=\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\varepsilon})$. By the prime number theorem,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}}  = 0.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}}  = \frac{{M(x)}}{x} - \int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{M(t)}}{{t^2 }}{\rm d}t} ,
$$
where
\begin{align*}
\frac{{M(x)}}{x} - \int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{M(t)}}{{t^2 }}{\rm d}t} & = \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2 + \varepsilon } ) + \mathcal{O}(1)\int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\rm d}t}{{t^{3/2 - \varepsilon } }}} \\ & = \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2 + \varepsilon } ) + \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2 + \varepsilon } ) = \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2 + \varepsilon } ).
\end{align*}
Now assume $G(x)=\mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2 + \varepsilon } )$. Then, by Abel's summation formula,
$$
M(x):=\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\mu (n)}  = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}n}  = x\,G(x) + \int_1^x {G(t)\,{\rm d}t} .
$$
Using our assumption, it follows that $M(x)=\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\varepsilon})$, which we know implies RH.

Comment: At the third line, why do the integration limit changes?

Comment: Because I added and subtracted $$
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{M(t)}}{{t^2 }}{\rm d}t} \quad \left( { = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\mu (n)}}{n}}  = 0} \right).
$$

Comment: Thanks. For the fourth line, if $\epsilon>1/2$, isn't the integral diverges?

Comment: You can assume that $0<\varepsilon<1/2$. Then the case $\varepsilon \ge 1/2$ follows trivially.

Comment: No need of the PNT if you are assuming that $\sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(n)n^{-s}$ converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ as it implies that $\sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(n)n^{-1}=\lim_{s\to 1} \sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(n)n^{-s}=0$ :-)

Comment: @reuns Good point, thank you.